# bookmarklet to save text from website

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping

Due to poor internal company system, I need to do the same data entry again and again. I was wondering if I could make my life easier by writing a script?

I need to capture text (certain paragraphs or data in table) from a web page and save it as a `.txt` file. I am thinking of trying to do this by using a bookmarklet with some javascript code.

1. How do I save the text that I need as .txt using bookmarklet/javascript?
2. `document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML` would also give me all the html code but than I need to spend a lot of time cleaning it up later. `.innerText` looks like something much better but based on what I have read this is not recommended?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what your actual question is -- is it about innerHTML vs innerText, or about writing a script to save content as a txt file?   Maybe you can post some code for what you have already tried.

Comment: `textContent` is valid property if you want to get text without html tags. For file saving read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found something that could be helpful: [link](https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/)

The only other idea I have is to write to the console with `console.log()`, then copy and paste it to where you need it.

Comment: Link only answers are a bad idea since the link may become invalid over time -- I would upvote if you had summarized the content of the link